# Is it possible to make game background filed as panoramic image in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

We are developing games for oil rig engineering. Is it possible to make game background filed as panoramic image in unity3d (as spherical or cubic panorama). We would like to add our other object as mesh generated in MAYA.

Answer (score 0):

Unity3D has a sky box feature, it is described in details [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Skybox.html).

In short you need to get 6 images for all sides of a cube that will be rendered on the background and assign them as textures in RenderFX/Skybox material in Unity.

Once you get the skybox material you can set it for camera, by switching camera clear flags to Skybox and adding Rendering->Skybox component with skybox material to camera object.

Or you can set this skybox material in Render Settings.

Skybox will be rendered before all other objects, so you can have all your other objects as a regular meshes in a scene, they will be rendered with skybox on background.